# Unknown chromium error: -6 (jquery mobile)

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, chromium

I'm working on an android native application, and I'm using a Webview to load my android_asset/www/index.html file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    final Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

This all works great, untill I place the import for the jquery-mobile js in the header:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

When I include the jquery mobile js into my html document, logcat gives me a Unknown chromium error -6. This doesn't happen when I include the normal jquery js.

I am running my application on nexus S with android 4.0.3

Is there anybody that has experience using this framework?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have similar problem with jquery mobile, whenever you include the js file, it will show Unknown chromium error: -6. Anyone have workaround?

Comment: I'm still getting the error, but it seems to give me no problems developping the application..

Comment: it causes my UI to freeze up; the main thread ends up waiting on a messagequeue poll !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are yet to find a solution, I came across the following links, while searching for the same problem:

[Phonegap Discussion Group](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/20979)

[Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436627/unknown-chromium-error-6-sencha-and-phonegap)