# Phonegap Android: Unknown chromium error: -6

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I'm creating a Phonegap Android app and I'm having trouble when adding a plugin to it. Cordova version is 2.2.0. I'm not using jQM or Sencha Touch. I test the app on Android 4.0.

The plugin I refer to is [Android Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker). This is my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      ...
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/application.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datePickerPlugin.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my main Java file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class looker extends DroidGap
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
                super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 7000);
            }
    }
```

So in order to understand if the problem is within the plugin, I **minimized** [this file](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/DatePicker/datePickerPlugin.js) in `assets/application.js` where all my minimized scripts I use are. I removed the script tag for the plugin from `index.html` and the plugin was working just fine! So it's got something to do with the URL's maybe?

**What have I tried so far?**

I was researching a lot and tried several solutions to other similar problems.

1. Made sure I have 3 /'s for the `loadUrl` in my main class:

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
         super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 7000);
       }
   ```

   Had that from the very beginning, **didn't make any difference**.
2. Tried calling super.init() before super.loadUrl(). **Didn't work as well**.
3. Tried this:

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       super.init();
       super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 6000);
       super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
   }
   ```

   **Still not fixing the problem.**
4. Checked if the file is loaded in the app, by adding an `alert();`. **It loads**.

That's in general. Will be glad to provide you with additional info if needed in order to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: confirm me that, you are trying to use DatePickerPlugin?

Comment: Yes, I'm using DatePickerPlugin. I've provided a link to it in the very beginning of the post. Though I'm quite sure it has nothing to do directly with the plugin, since that problem happens with other files I try to load from index.html

Comment: did you exactly follow Readme for integration?

Comment: As I have written in my post, the plugin works. Integration of the plugin is not the issue here. I've minimized it in application.js and it works great! Still when I add the plugin in index.html, I get the chromium error. Paths are ok also...

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436627/unknown-chromium-error-6-sencha-and-phonegap) Try this.

Comment: This fix is specifically for Sencha. Knowing this fix, I wrote at the very beginning I'm not using Sencha. Please read the post again in order to get more into the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Now might be a good time to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the guide and was able to get the plugin working just fine.

However, I was able to replicate the "Unknown chromium error: -6" when I had this in my config.xml:

`<plugin name="DatePickerPlugin1" value="com.phonegap.plugin.DatePickerPlugin"/>`

Make sure that the "name" attribute in the XML is DatePickerPlugin, since that is the name that the JavaScript code uses for the plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/DatePicker/datePickerPlugin.js#L33

There may be other ways to generate the same error though. If this doesn't help, can you post or link to your HTML file that actually calls out to this plugin, as well as your config.xml? (Make sure you are using a res/xml/config.xml and not res/xml/plugins.xml which has been deprecated here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20Android

Comment: Here is my [config.xml](http://pastie.org/7585131#2,19). The code that calls the plugin is in `assets/application.js`. It is the same as in the example. This file is consisting of all of the scripts I'm using, because I'm using Backbone.js and there are is a lot of .js files. In short - I have a web version of it, I minimize the JS files to the Android app and build it. So far there has been no trouble with any functionality, until now. Let me remind that if I minimize the `datePickerPlugin.js` along with all the others it works just fine.

Comment: Alright so the app works fine when everything is minimized. When datePickerPlugin.js is not minimized but everything else is, the app falls apart. Is that right? What happens when nothing is minimized? Does it still break? If not, that's good news because it means the problem is the minimized non-plugin JS code is probably using a minimized version of the datePickerPlugin.js filename or something....? The config.xml looks fine.

Comment: So I debugged for a while, here's the case. If I minimize `cordova-2.2.0.js` and `datePickerPlugin.js` alongside with all the JS files it works. If I remove them from the minimized file and only add them to the `index.html` the datepicker returns the chromium error. At no point the app fails, it runs all the time in both cases. When I alert inside the `datePickerPlugin.js` I get the alert, so the file loads. But when I `alert(window.plugins.datePicker);` on 57 row it returns undefined for some reason...

Comment: What happens if you alert window.plugins only? Or better yet, something like ```var output = '';
for (property in window) {
  output += property + ': ' + window[property]+'; ';
}
alert(output);``` which will hopefully show us that the plugin is at least registered.

Comment: `alert(window.plugins)` returns undefined. This is what I get with the for loop: http://cl.ly/image/1u41451A2u0H . In fact I use Backbone.js and every element renders with the respective view of the template it is in. Which means that on document.ready I don't have the input elements, that trigger the plugin when clicked. Those inputs are created when the view is rendered. I wonder if that could be the case?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error: Unknown Chromium error -6"
and my mistake was wrong partials path.

I had to specify **relative paths** for the partials.

When you use ng-include or the module **ngRoute**,
instead of this:

> > ng-include="'/partials/file.html'"

put this one:

> > ng-include="'partials/file.html'"

If you look I removed the first slash in the path.

This approach solved my chromium error.