# Unknown chromium error: -6 (simple project)

Tags: cordova

I get Unknown chromium error: -6 but add nothing to my project. There is no plugin, no javascript..
Should I ignore it or is it important?

I didn't find solution, thanks in advance.

I'm using codova 2.7

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PhoneGap</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Hello PhoneGap</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

XML

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.diyet.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that's the original project code? If so, did you try rebooting your computer or reinstalling.

Comment: I rebooted,deleted,reinstalled, delete workspace, everthing.

Comment: Is private library important? :D

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014849/phonegap-android-unknown-chromium-error-6

Comment: I saw that question but his problem about plugin but i have no plugin. I add private library and jar files from order and export, nothing has change

Comment: "I add private library...nothing has changed" Clearly, you _did_ change something. You added a library. Do you get the error if you _don't_ add the private library and JARs?

Comment: I mean, I get error AGAIN

Comment: Was there any solution to this?  I am getting the same error when upgrading from 2.2 to 2.9.

Comment: i didnt found solution, sorry.I ignored it